# RegEx not processing all lines in a tab-delimited text

Tags: regex, lines, csv

Hey i am totally new to RegEx, can maybe someone help me with this problem?

https://regex101.com/r/mS2oB5/4

My Regular Expression

```
(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\d)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+?)\t(\w.+)
```

The Text File (tab-delimited)

```
C-380_TF-4318-028   none    ID  4   none    none    1.1 c   1.4 none    none    26  RB 2,5%
C-366_TF-4269-012   none    REW 7   none    none    1.1 c   17.1    none    none    28  RB 7%
C-1008_TF-4480-011  none    none    0   WT  H   1.1 c   17.16   none    none    24  R
C-1008_TF-4480-006  none    none    0   WT  H   1.1 c   2   none    none    36  R
C-388_TF-4351-022   none    none    0   WM  none    1.1 c   20.3    none    none    21  R
C-388_TF-4351-019   none    none    0   WM  none    1.1 c   22.3    none    none    32  R
C-397_TF-4437-001   none    REW 7   WM  none    1.1 c   26  none    none    30  RB 7,5%
C-388_TF-4351-013   none    none    0   WM  none    1.3 b   17.3    none    none    14  RB
C-366_TF-4269-004   none    none    0   none    none    2.1 17  none    none    n.d.    R 
C-1008_TF-4480-013  none    REW 7   WT  H   2.1 c   1   none    none    28  RB
C-380_TF-4318-026   none    REW 7   none    none    2.1 c   1.2 none    none    28  RB 2,5%
C-380_TF-4318-016   none    none    0   none    none    2.1 c   17.1    none    none    28  RB 2,5%
C-380_TF-4318-015   none    none    0   none    none    2.1 c   6.36    none    none    26  RB 10%
C-397_TF-4437-002   none    none    0   WM  none    2.3 c   15.2    none    none    28  RB 5%
C-385_TF-4344-000b  none    ED  23  none    none    2.3 c   2   10.4.3  none    26,5    CO 100%
C-385_TF-4344-000a  none    REW 7   none    none    2.5.1 c 20.2    none    none    30  RB 21%
C-366_TF-4269-022   none    KW  7   none    none    2.5.2 b 17.1    none    none    10  RB 7%
```

Why is the Expression working on some entries and not working on the other ones, i have no clue? Thanks for ur help in advance!

Comment: `.` also matches `\w` and `\t`. Have you noticed the number of steps your regex requires to complete? And since it is a tab delimited file, why not split the lines with a tab? Ok, see  [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/pR8bJ1/1) (rather meaningless, since you just need to split each line with `\t`).

Comment: thanks for your help wiktor! that really did the trick. as i said, sorry for my sully questions, image me beeing a 3-year old learning the first steps into more then simple markup....

Comment: Better uses a CSV parser for that - with proper settings, it will parse this in no time efficiently and correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual issue is that you require each item to be at least 2 characters long with `\w.+?`. `\w` matches 1 word character and `.+?` matches at least 1 character. The last `\w.+` also requires at least 2 symbols. Also,  mind that `.` matches both `\w` and `\d` and `\t` thus, your regex is very inefficient.

The best way to process the file will be to split it into lines, and then split each line with a tab. Surely, a CSV parser is highly recommended.

Just for educational purposes, see [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/pR8bJ1/1), where each item on a row is matched with `[^\t]*`  - 0+ characters other than a tab, and `^` / `$` anchors to reduce backtracking overhead.

Comment: thank you again for your help, i appreciate it a lot :thumbsup!